# Pubnub receiving duplicate messages in one channel, but not in another channel

Tags: reactjs, pubnub

Business Code:

```
const NodeDetails = (): React.Node => {
  ......
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader loaded={false} />}>
      <Pubnub_A />
      <Content
        ......
      />
    </Suspense>
  );

function Content(): React.Node {
  ......
  return (
    <>
       <Pubnub_B />
       ......
    </>
  );
```

Pubnub_A:

```
export default function Pubnub_A(): null {
  pubNubSub({
    namespace: "test_A",
    namespaceId: "test_namespaceId",
    event: "DONE",
    callback: () => {
      console.log('Pubnub_A')
    },
  });
  return null;
}
```

Pubnub_B:

```
export default function Pubnub_B(): null {
  pubNubSub({
    namespace: "test_B",
    namespaceId: "test_namespaceId",
    event: "DONE",
    callback: () => {
      console.log('Pubnub_B')
    },
  });
  return null;
}
```

pubNubSub:

```
export type Sub = {
  namespace: string,
  namespaceId?: ?string,
  event?: ?string,
  callback: EventCallback,
};

export default function pubNubSub(
  sub: Sub
) {
  const subs = useMemo(() => [sub], [sub]);

  const {client} = useContext(PubNubContext);

  useEffect(() => {
      const ids = subs.map(sub =>
        {
          return client.subscribe(
          {
            namespace: sub.namespace,
            namespaceId: sub.namespaceId,
            event: sub.event,
          },
          sub.callback
        )
        }
      );
      return function clear() {
        ids.forEach(id => {
          client.unsubscribe(id);
        });
      };
  }, [subs, client]);
}
```

In Business Code, Pubnub_A receives one message, but Pubnub_B receives duplicate message when I refresh the page.
If I put Pubnub_A and Pubnub_B together, like:

```
const NodeDetails = (): React.Node => {
  ......
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader loaded={false} />}>
      <Pubnub_A />
      <Pubnub_B />
      <Content
        ......
      />
    </Suspense>
  );

function Content(): React.Node {
  ......
  return (
    <>
       ......
    </>
  );
```

or

```
const NodeDetails = (): React.Node => {
  ......
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader loaded={false} />}>
      <Content
        ......
      />
    </Suspense>
  );

function Content(): React.Node {
  ......
  return (
    <>
      <Pubnub_A />
      <Pubnub_B />
       ......
    </>
  );
```

Both Pubnub_A and Pubnub_B receive one message.

If I delete Pubnub_A in origin Business Code, Pubnub_B receive one message.

It seems that Pubnub_A and Pubnub_B can't be in different components. Or the later will receive duplicate messages.

I want to know why it happens and how to make Pubnub_A and Pubnub_B receive one message in origin code. Thanks!

Comment: I know React at a basic level and I know useEffect can lead to undesired/unexpect behavior and perhaps other hooks like useMemo may as well. Your code has many factors that could contribute to the dupe messages but I can assure you that it isn't PubNub server or client SDK that's doing it. Somehow, there are two instances of the PubNub_A that are getting created. Is there any way to simplify your code and test, then add a level/layer, test and do that until you are back to this code? I'll get our React engineers to take a look, too.

Comment: What name and version of PubNub module which you are using? Asking, because I don't recognise `subscribe` function, which let you pass callback.

Comment: `useEffect` hook will be called with each render, because `subs` won't be same object, as it has been passed with previous render (`Object.is` for objects verify that it should be exact same object passed by reference, but in your code they constructed with each call) - you need to _memorise_ it (you can use `useCallback` hook to memorise functions as well).

Comment: The version of pubnub is 7.2

Comment: @Hayden you can check in [this](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/api-reference/publish-and-subscribe#methods-3) doc for subscribe function, that there is no callback passed to `subscribe` function as well as no `namespace` and `namespaceId`. Is it possible to show what do you have related to **PubNub** client in youre `package.json`?